# LitElement with data from Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, lit-element, lit-html

I've been trying to dynamically insert data from Firestore into my component.

Currently, I'm using the `firstUpdated()` lifecycle. My code works but it fell like there's a better way of doing this.

This is my current component.

```
static get properties() {
  return {  
     firebaseData: {type:Object},
    }
}
constructor() {
  super()
  this.firebaseData = {}
}

firstUpdated() {
  firestore.doc(`...`).get()
  .then(doc => {this.firebaseData = doc.data()})
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
render() {
  return html `${firebaseData.title}`
}
```

I was hope someone with more experience would be open to sharing their knowledge. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`firstUpdated` should be used when you need to interact with shadow DOM elements inside your web component, as they aren't created until then. It's the earliest moment when you can be sure your component DOM exists.

I would prefer to do the firebase call earlier, even in the constructor.

The idea is, your `firebase` call isn't dependent of the rendering, so you could directly do it at the earliest moment, and as in the callback of the function you update the `firebaseData` property, a new rendering cycle will be done then.